# PayPal iOS Network Connection Was Lost

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I actually posted this question on [PayPal Repository GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/435), but no one was answering me.

The PayPal SDK works so fine when using a PayPal Account, but when I try to use Pay with card, I can't connect to the PayPal Server, and there is no debug logs, only this:

> 2016-07-18 10:00:03.447 UPlant[23489:265771] NSScanner: nil string
>   argument 2016-07-18 10:00:04.036 UPlant[23489:265771] Can't find
>   keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad;
>   using 563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default 2016-07-18
>   10:00:04.077 UPlant[23489:265771] NSScanner: nil string argument
>   2016-07-18 10:00:04.077 UPlant[23489:265771] NSScanner: nil string
>   argument 2016-07-18 10:00:04.077 UPlant[23489:265771] NSScanner: nil
>   string argument 2016-07-18 10:00:08.415 UPlant[23489:265771] Can't
>   find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard
>   iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using
>   563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default 2016-07-18 10:00:10.070
>   UPlant[23489:265771] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for
>   keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using
>   563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

**Additional Information**

**Mode (Mock/Sandbox/Live)**: Sandbox

**PayPal iOS SDK Version:** sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.14.2

**iOS Version and Device (iOS 8.x, iOS 9.3 on an iPhone 6s, etc.):** iOS 9.3 iPhone 5 Simulator

**PayPal-Debug-ID(s) (from any logs):** No debug logs

After attempting the PayPal to do the transaction with Card, it pops up an alert saying

> The Network Connection Was Lost.

Any idea on this why is this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: I am also getting this error. But I am unable to found a solution for it.

Comment: hi @MayankPurwar I already solved this. I was waiting for my friend's blog (tutorial about this) before I close this question. So basically you'll need to register a sandbox account and use that card number, not the 42424242, or whatever :) Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using sandbox card number but its showing that error.

Comment: did you set your environment on your codes? It should be in sandbox mode too.

Comment: YES. I have done that also